# Replace category values by ID and day

Tags: r

I have a list of IDs that can fall into one of two categories each day, let's call them 'A' and 'B'. An ID typically shows up between 0-2 times a day but can appear more often. Because the data quality isn't great, some IDs show up as *both* A and B on a particular day. So instead of looking like this:

```
ID    Date        Category
1111  2020-09-10  A
1111  2020-09-10  A
1111  2020-09-10  A
```

They look like this:

```
ID    Date        Category
1111  2020-09-10  A
1111  2020-09-10  B
1111  2020-09-10  B
```

I need to fix it so that if an ID is part of category A in a day, then all the records for that ID for that day shows category A. But if all records for that day show up as 'B', regardless of how that ID was categorized previously, it will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library("dplyr")

df = data.frame("ID" = c(1111, 1111, 1111, 2222, 2222, 2222),
                "Date" = c("2020-09-10", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-10",
                           "2020-09-11", "2020-09-11", "2020-09-11"),
                "Category" = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Category = ifelse("A" %in% Category, "A", "B"))
```

```
     ID Date       Category
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
1  1111 2020-09-10 A       
2  1111 2020-09-10 A       
3  1111 2020-09-10 A       
4  2222 2020-09-11 B       
5  2222 2020-09-11 B       
6  2222 2020-09-11 B
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are only looking for a single instance of 'A' for 'Category' per group, we can use `if/else`, which seeks a logical expression that returns `length` 1

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID, Date) %>%
   mutate(Category = if("A" %in% Category) "A" else "B")
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Date [2]
#     ID Date       Category
#  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   
#1  1111 2020-09-10 A       
#2  1111 2020-09-10 A       
#3  1111 2020-09-10 A       
#4  2222 2020-09-11 B       
#5  2222 2020-09-11 B       
#6  2222 2020-09-11 B
```

Or with `any`

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID, Date) %>%
   mutate(Category = if(any(Category == "A")) "A" else "B")
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1111, 1111, 1111, 2222, 2222, 2222),
                "Date" = c("2020-09-10", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-10",
                           "2020-09-11", "2020-09-11", "2020-09-11"),
                "Category" = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
```